# select _DONE_ report requests from amazon php

Tags: php, report, amazon-mws

Here is my code to select order report from amazon using mws  feed api.This is working fine,but now it returns all `_GET_ORDERS_DATA_` type reports,but i only need to get the reports having status `_DONE_`.is it possible to do with PHP?

[Here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_IN/reports/Reports_GetReportRequestList.html) i found an option for `ReportProcessingStatusList` but  i unable to set with this SDk,how to set this option?

```
 $parameters = array (
   'Merchant' => MERCHANT_ID,
   'MaxCount' => 100
 );
 $request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportRequestListRequest($parameters);

 $TypeList = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_TypeList();
 $TypeList->setType('_GET_ORDERS_DATA_');
 $request->setReportTypeList($TypeList);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you are calling `GetReportRequestList`, which is part of the *Reports API*, not Feeds API. You can limit results to a specific report type by requesting the list like this:

```
$request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportRequestListRequest(array(
  "ReportProcessingStatusList.Status.1": "_DONE_"
));
```

By the way, besides the API reference documentation, the Scratchpad helps a lot finding and testing out parameters: https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html (use the proper URL that matches your country/region)